# Big picture: Ceiling LED control

Tags: arduino, led, power-electronics, led-driver, lighting

I have been looking at ceiling LEDs for a while; I am owner-building a house ATM, and "wondered" how I can control the ceiling LEDs -- most 9-12W, probably 30-ish of them; in 3-4 different zones.
Smaller rooms (3 x 3 m2) may have two zones and 4-6 LED lights.
Ideally say if a square room has 4, each should be able to be controlled individually (always on|off, dim).

The "wondering" part is the approach, given these constraints:

1. while I like DIY wherever possible; using Arduinos to do all
   sorts of tasks; integrated with openHAB, I am conscious that 230V
   needs to be wired by a licensed electrician (law in Australia; DIY =
   illegal). This implies to me (I could be wrong) that I should use
   standard LED bulb + driver + plug combinations; dimmable. Reasoning:
   because the LEDs have a plug, the whole set can be replaced in case
   of a fault (or desire to change any LED parameter, colour, wattage,
   angle, etc.) by a layman.
2. If I were to control the LED bulbs directly (on|off, dim), I
   would need a driver to supply the right V and constant A these LEDs
   are running on. They are presumably different for each wattage LED?!
   If the bulb has to be replaced, and say, the Wattage no longer
   exists, the driver would either need to be changed too or
   reconfigured to suit the new LED.
3. would it then be best to wire each LED to a central location,
   which gives me the benefit of grouping the lights as I need them;
   planning and real world might change, hence, the need to be able to
   reconfigure easily.
4. Assuming I install standard sets (LED, driver, plug) would it be
   best to build triac circuitry to control each LED fixture?
   (Ultimately controlled by some sort of micro-controller, e.g Arduino.
   If so, which is the best way to do this?

With the constraints stated above, is it the best approach to use a multi-channel triac set-up to dim each standard LED fixture?

I looked at say 9W LEDs, they come with a driver; I could build my own driver to control this LED, but then I assume I need different drivers for a different wattage LED?!
The solution should be also cost-effective.

Any hints, thoughts, questions and feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Parallel thinking. Off the shelf smart led bulbs, with a custom app or RPi. Your still be programming the behavior, but in a different environment.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not really a fit here, both as it is too broad, and because it approaches the problem from a user-of-technology or home improvement perspective rather than an EE design one.  Specifics in the process of creating of one of the modules you might end up buying would be on topic here, but picking which one to buy is not. That doesn't mean it isn't a valid question, just that it is is not within the mission of this site.  Both home improvement and IoT stack exchange sites exist, but beware that they also require greater specificity than in your current wording.

Comment: Sorry... didn't know that... was thinking the brains exist from an engineering perspective to understand what I am after, or what could be a good solution; rather than try this try that... but actually grasping the underlying problem, and the big picture -- hence, the low specificity you're highlighting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: it is this type of discussion I wanted to avoid: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226047/dimmable-ac-led-controlled-by-arduino?rq=1 because it does not produce an outcome, nor does it look at a high level strategy.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of constant-current LED driver ICs with PWM control for dimming. You can easily generate a PWM signal from an Arduino, although the IC only has four PWM controllers (so a single Arduino can only control four lights without larger coding effort).

To use these, you need a sensible DC power supply (somewhere between 5 and 12V), which also solves the issue with wiring, as you are using off-the-shelf components on the 230V side. Current carrying capacity on the DC side is an issue though.

I've built a small board for four LEDs once, with up to 1A per LED, adjustable through a resistor divider. I control one of these from an Arduino, and use an Osram OSTAR RGBW LED with 750mA/channel, works fine.

[image: LED driver]

Material cost for the board:

- 5,96 EUR for the driver IC
- 1 EUR for the inductors
- 2,40 EUR for the flyback diodes
- 1 EUR for the current sensing resistors
- 2 EUR for remaining smaller parts

Comment: Thank you for the post... can I ask you to think at a higher level: Given my constraints, what is one good solution to the problem. E.g. should I dim individual LEDs? Or in groups? Buy 'plugable' LEDs (LED + driver + plug); or should I DIY. Is the latter (which I am not afraid off) sensible, given the constraints and bearing in mind good engineering practice. In other words, before jumping to a solution, the problem needs to be understood. Pls don't get me wrong, I appreciate your input. My thinking is still stuck at the (unresolved) big picture. :)

Comment: @MaxG, it depends on what you want, for the most part. A setup with individually addressible LEDs can do nice effects, but is more expensive to set up. In my setup I have eight LEDs total for the entire room, with RGB color and an extra boost for white light (I've built a variant of the [GLaDOS lamp](http://ytec3d.com/glados-lamp/), but paid close to 200 EUR for the lighting electronics alone. You can also go for many small LEDs with strips of WS2812 or APA102, these can also be controlled from an Arduino or [compatibles](http://www.misc.name/fadecandy/).